# Angular2 минимизация приложения. Оптимизация времени загрузки

Tags: angular2, минификация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с оптимизацией приложения. Есть приложения на Angular2. Минимизацию делал по этой [статье](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/). Без webpack. 
Командами

```
 browserify -s main dist/main.js > dist/bundle.js
```

и

```
uglifyjs dist/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/bundle.min.js
```

получилось минимизировать бандл, но он занимает 1.7 метра. 
Структура app.module.ts проекта очень большая на мой взгляд.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2PaginationModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    DatePickerModule,
    Ng2GoogleChartsModule,
    routing,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAqIBAiCeLH9A5I5lqEK3iK1j3gAmL3yIg',
      libraries:['geometry', 'places']
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    RecoveryComponent,
    BaseComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ActiveDriversComponent,
    AdminsComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    DriversApplicationsComponent,
    ActiveDriverComponent,
    ActivationComponent,
    OrdersCanceledComponent,
    AllOrderForDriverComponent,
    NewUserComponent,
    DriverRateComponent,
    DeterminationErrors,
    HttpPopupErrors,
    TranslatePipe,
    CKEditorComponent,
    OrdersComponent,
    SelectLanguageComponent,
    SelectRoleComponent,
    SelectNoticeComponent,
    CurrentOrdersComponent,
    NotConfirmedComponent,
    DeferredOrdersComponent,
    CompletedOrdersComponent,
    AbolishedOrdersComponent,
    DriversOffersComponent,
    EvaluationEditorComponent,
    NewOrderComponent,
    OrderInfoComponent,
    PermissionDeniedComponent,
    SelectBoxComponent,
    NewsComponent,
    CreateNewsComponent,
    EditNewsComponent,
    PublishedNewsComponent,
    SelectFilterComponent,
    ChangeStatusComponent,
    PaymentsTemplatesComponent,
    PaymentsComponent,
    NewTemplateComponent,
    NewTemplateComponent,
    ChangePasswordComponent,
    EditTemplateComponent,
    SupportComponent,
    TemplatesComponent,
    DraftsComponent,
    AppealsMessagesComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    NotificationComponent,
    CountriesComponent,
    AddCountryComponent,
    AddCityComponent,
    EditCountryComponent,
    EditCityComponent,
    CurrentBalanceComponent,
    MarkerClusterDirective,
    DriverMapDirective,
    PersonalDirective,
    AllInfoDirective,
    StatisticDirective,
    SearchDirective,
    DateRangePickerDirective,
    PersonalAutoDirective,
    DocumentsDirective,
    PaginationDirective,
    HelpersDirective,
    SimpleRateDirective,
    FilterPipe,
    PluralPipe
  ],
  providers: [
    Urls,
    User,
    SearchModel,
    HttpService,
    CurrencyService,
    Md5,
    DeterminationErrorService,
    TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS,
    TranslateService,
    LocationService
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  bootstrap:    [ MainComponent ]
})
```

В связи с этим есть вопросы. Поможет ли в данной ситуации ленивая загрузка модулей, и если поможет то как разбить на отдельные модули данную структуру (не понятен сам принцип)?
Возможно ли как то ещё оптимизировать приложение?

Comment: чисто ради любопытства - Вы пробовали скомпилировать с одним компонентом? Просто к angular2 столько всякой ерунды нужно подключать, что мне кажется что весь вес это и есть angular.

Comment: Да, делал 600 кб.   Конечно много, но моего кода тоже на 1мб получается.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, посмотри про [AoT и TreeShacking](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)

Comment: Про treesharking читал в той же статье, но он как я понял снизит примерно на 10% вес файла. А про aot не совсем понял, как он компилирует, что снижает вес конечного бандла?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, он убирает сам компилятор ангуляра и оставляет только небольшую часть, фреймворк необходимый для работы. TreeShaking удаляет неиспользуемые импорты. Поэтому на сколько снизится размер скриптов зависит только от того как они сейчас написаны

Comment: спасибо большое за подсказку, сейчас попробую. Если что обращусь с  вопросами )

Comment: компиляция  в aot, не проходит (tsc -p  tsconfig-aot.json) потому выдаёт большое количество ошибок, хотя обычная компиляция tsc -w пусть и с ошибками, но работает  и  компилирует файлы. Возможно ли как то обойти эти ошибки и скомпилировать его?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, для aot там вроде их компилятор нужно `ngc`

Comment: Да, таки надо ngc. как оказалось большая проблема это всё делать без angular-cli

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, то есть проблема решилась? можешь тогда написать ответ с пояснениями что делал и каких результатов добился

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблему решил так. Сначала решил костылём, а потом создал новый проект с angular-cli и добавил в него свои модули

**Обходное решение (костыль)**

Так как скомпилировать проект без angular-cli не получилось - пришлось сделать html костяк с лоудером и вставить в index.html.

*index.html*

```
<body>

<div id="auth_" style="display: none; height: 100%;">
  <div class="start-wrapper">
    <div class="popup-main-wrapper">
      <div class="tax-wrapper">

      </div>
      <div class="popup-title-wrapper">
        <p class="popup-title">Авторизация</p>
      </div>
      <div class="popup-body-wrapper" style="position: relative">
        <div id="ajax-loader__auth" class="ajax-loader__auth">
          <img src="/img/3.gif" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 .....
 <my-app></my-app>
 ...

  $(document).ready(function() {$('#auth_').show();)} // Показывает html блок с лоудер
```

В файле скрывал блок *auth.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit() {
    $('#auth_').hide();
}
```

Это решение быстрое и не требует большого количества времени.

Второй путь более сложный и трудоёмкий.

**Создание приложения с помощью angular-cli**

Устанавливаем локально angular-cli. Для этого выполнить в консоли.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Второй шаг перенос кода. Это самый сложный и рутинный этап, так как на проекте была версия 2.0.0, а версия с которой создаётся проект - 2.3. Поэтому пришлось переписывать импорты некоторых компонентов. Но в результате что бы релизнуть

Создаём билд AOT

```
ng build --prod --aot
ng serve --prod --aot
```